# Traversing an evaluation context in K?

Tags: kframework

Contexts are often in a form `#freezer_;__BILS-SYNTAX1_ ( ! _1 )`.
I'd like to write a function that traverses evaluation contexts.
How does one pattern match evaluation contexts and traverse them?

EDIT: to give an example, if I want to log evaluation contexts I've seen so far into a file, I would need to write a function that converts an evaluation context into a string, and then print it via system calls. Is pattern matching evaluation contexts possible to do? alternatively, is there a built-in "to-string" function in K?

Comment: You'd probably need to write heating and cooling rules manually to do this. What's your use case? There may be a better way of doing this.

Comment: I have a syntax with expressions `Exp ::= Exp ; Exp | "new" KVar "in" Exp | "!" KVar | KVar ":=" Exp | Int | Exp "+" Exp` and at certain intermediate steps, I'd like to be able to count the number of assignments `:=` and dereferencing `!` that are pending. Another solution I was thinking of is to parse terms such that they always hold this number with them, but I would still have to traverse the evaluation contexts to know the total. What do you suggest?